# Como passa a variavel via $_POST

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou criando um trecho de código onde eu atribuo os dados inseridos em um `array` no `javascript` e passando para o próximo programa. Mas o problema é que se eu usar o `$_GET` ele não pode dar suporte quando chegar ao um numero máximo de caracteres, ai gostaria de passar via `$_POST`, mas não estou achando uma maneira certa de pegar a `variável` do `javascript` e armazenar na oculta para passar por `post`.

**Código:**

```
<html>
<form name="sai_frm_incl" method="POST">
    <body>  
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="Silver" align="center">    
            <? 
             echo('<input type="hidden" name="w_patr_seri" value="' .$w_patr_seri.'" />'); 
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>   
                    <font face="arial" align="center" color="blue" size="-1">Teste</font><br>
                    <input type="text" name="nm_cb_tama_moni" id="id_tama_moni" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" value="">
    </table>
    </body>
</form>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function move_patr(Origem)
{
   v_patr = v_patr + document.forms['sai_frm_incl'].nm_cb_tama_moni.value;
}
```

Ou seja, eu quero armazenar o conteúdo de `v_patr` na `$w_patr_seri`!

Comment: Você quer enviar um formulário por ajax? Já tentou o jQuery?
`$.ajax({type:'POST',...});`

Comment: Não entendi bem, parece mais um problema de php… E as marcações devem ser <?php … ?> senão pode não funcionar.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, eu estava utilizando v_patr para pegar no próximo programa via $_GET o conteúdo, mas o problema é que o GET só tem suporte a um numero máximo de caracteres, assim resolvi armazenar o conteúdo de v_patr em uma variável hidden e passar via POST!

Comment: Tá meio difícil entender sua lógica, mas vamos lá. Você quer que um valor do `javascript`, seja passado para um `form`, para que o PHP receba esses dados? Onde está o elemento `document.forms['sai_frm_incl'].nm_cb_tama_moni.value;` que você está pegando o valor? Não o encontrei no seu código.

Comment: Erro meu @KaduAmaral, acabei copiando o trecho errado. O trecho seria esse `<input type="text" name="nm_cb_tama_moni" id="id_tama_moni" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" value="">`. E sim quero que o valor do `JS` seja pego pelo `PHP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enviando os dados

Para enviar um valor por `POST`, via javascript, o jeito mais fácil é usando **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**.

### Usando jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'pagina-para-receber-os-dados.php',
    type: 'POST', // GET é o padrão
    dataType: 'json', // pode ser xml, json, script, ou html, o jQuery também detecta automáticamente, 
                      // mas é  bom sempre informar
    data: {'vpart': $('#id_tama_moni').val()}, // Também pode usar serialize para enviar todo o formulário
    success: function(data){ // script executado, quando o ajax é enviado com sucesso
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.msg);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { // Script executado quando houve erro
       console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
       console.log('----------------------------------');
       console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
       console.log('----------------------------------');
       console.log(errorThrown);
       alert('Houve um erro ao enviar os dados');

    }
});
```

### Javascript puro

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","pagina-para-receber-os-dados.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
valor = document.getElementById('id_tama_moni').value;
xmlhttp.send("vpart="+valor);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { // script executado, quando o ajax é enviado com sucesso
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    } else { // Script executado quando houve erro
        alert('Houve um erro ao enviar os dados');
    }
}
```

---

## Recebendo os dados

**PHP** (pagina-para-receber-os-dados.php)

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['vpart'])){
        echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Dados recebidos com sucesso pelo servidor'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Os dados não foram recebidos pelo servidor'));
    }
    exit;
```

---

## Alterando valor de um elemento

### Usando jQuery

```
v_patr = v_patr + $("#nm_cb_tama_moni").val();
$("#w_patr_seri").val(v_patr);
```

### Usando Javascript

```
v_patr = v_patr + document.forms['sai_frm_incl'].nm_cb_tama_moni.value;
document.getElementById("w_patr_seri").value = v_patr;
```

### HTML

```
<html>
  <head><title>Titulo da Pagina</title></head>
  <body>  
    <form name="sai_frm_incl" method="POST">
      <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" bgcolor="Silver" align="center">    
            <input type="hidden" name="w_patr_seri" id="w_patr_seri" value="<?=$w_patr_seri?>" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font face="arial" align="center" color="blue" size="-1">Teste</font><br>
            <input type="text" name="nm_cb_tama_moni" id="id_tama_moni" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obs.: Coloque um ID no campo HIDDEN que você quer atribuir o valor