# Parametros multiplos em xmlhttp.send();

Tags: javascript, ajax, formulário

Estou fazendo uma inserção no banco de dados com ajax, o ajax esa funcionando, porém a inserção não está sendo feita corretamente, acredito que seja porque estou passando os parametros de forma incorreta no método send();. Preciso passar o nome e a idade no método. Eis o código:

HTML:

```
<h1> Cadastre-se em nosso site </h1>
    <div id="exibeCont"></div>

        <form action="servico.php?p=cadUsr" method="POST" id="frmCadUsr">
            Nome: <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="txtNome" id="txtNome"/>
            Idade: <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="txtIdade" id="txtIdade"/>

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
```

o PHP:

```
function cadUsr(){
    require("dbCon.php");
    require("mdl_usuario.php");

        $usr = $_POST["txtNome"];
        $idade = $_POST["txtIdade"];

        $resultado = usuario_cadastrar($con,$usr,$idade);

            if($resultado){
                echo "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso";
            } else {
                echo "O cadastro falhou";
            }
    }
```

Funçao PHP para inserir:

```
function usuario_cadastrar($conexao,$nome,$idade){


        if($nome == "" && $idade == ""){
            return false;
        }





        $sql = sprintf("insert into usuario (nome,idade) values ('%s',%s)",$nome,$idade);

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

            return $resultado;
    }
```

E o AJAX:

```
window.onload = function(){

            var xmlhttp;
            var frm = document.querySelector("#frmCadUsr");
            var url = frm.getAttribute("action");
            var nm = document.querySelector("#txtNome").value;
            var idade = document.querySelector("#txtIdade").value;

            frm.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                try{
                    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
                    xmlhttp.send(nm+idade);

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                            alert("Deu certo");
                        }
                    }
                } catch(err){
                    alert("Ocorreu um erro.<br />"+ err);
                }
            });

}
```

Recebo o alert com a mensagem "Deu certo", porém a inserção não é realizada.

Comment: Onde defines esta função:         $resultado = usuario_cadastrar($con,$usr,$idade); ?

Comment: @Sergio, acabei de atualizar o código com a função em questão !

Comment: Onde estás a chamar `cadUsr()`? dá-te algum erro no PHP?

Comment: @Sergio, obrigado pela ajuda, encontrei o verdadeiro problema e já postei a resposta !

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como passa a variavel via $\_POST](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34648/como-passa-a-variavel-via-post)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a checar pela resposta (da minha pergunta) é claramente notável que está pergunta nada tem a ver com a minha. O meu problema acontecia devido a ausência do método xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");, que eu desconhecia ser obrigatório, e isso não é citado em momento algum na outra pergunta.

Comment: @anuseranother uma pergunta ser duplicidade de outra não a torna "pior" ou algo do tipo, apenas "linka" uma na outra. Não leve a mal por favor.

Comment: Não levo, desculpe se fui rude, minha intenção certamente não foi essa ! Só queria explicar mesmo. Mais uma vez me desculpe se fui grosseiro e obrigado pela atenção !

Comment: @anuseranother não foi grosseiro não, fique tranquilo. Parabéns pela resposta, a dica do `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` é muito importante :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para além [do que o @sergio referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77792/129), faltava inserir o cabeçalho `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`.

Este cabeçalho é padrão na de todos os forms em html, porém ao desabilitar o padrão do formulario, ele perde esse valor. Retirei o formulario e deixei apenas os campos de texto, e adicionei. A `função ajax()` ficou desta forma:

```
function ajax(){

            var xmlhttp;    
            var nm = document.querySelector("#txtNome").value;
            var idade = document.querySelector("#txtIdade").value;

                try{
                    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("POST","servico.php",true);

                    /*setRequestHeader(Content-type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded), esta
                    função adiciona ao cabeçalho que o request feito ao servidor será um conteudo,
                    e o conteudo sera levado pela url como em um form.
                    o application/x-www-form-urlencoded é um dos cabeçalhos para enviar dados
                    através de HTTP. Ele faz com o que os dados enviados sejam guardados em uma
                    querystring(parametros de url), e é essencial quando se envia um dado para
                    o servidor.

                    Para enviar um dado para o servidor é necessário atribuir algum tipo de
                    cabeçalho para o HTTP.*/
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                    xmlhttp.send("txtNome=" + nm + "&txtIdade="+idade + "&p=cadUsr");

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                            alert("Deu certo");
                            //console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                } catch(err){
                    alert("Ocorreu um erro.<br />"+ err);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens de colocar os dados que queres enviar no formato *query string*. Ou seja:

```
chave1=valor1&chave2=valor2
```

Assim em vêx de `nm + idade` deves usar assim:

```
var dados = 'txtNome=' + nm + '&txtIdade=' + idade;
xmlhttp.send(dados);
```

Comment: Obrigado ! Porém ainda não funcionou. Dando um console.log, ele mostra que fez a query corretamente, e o ajax também me da um retorno positivo porém não insere no banco de dados !

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava tendo dificuldades com o meu também, aí coloquei o código sugerido:

```
 xmlreq.open("POST","inserir.php",true);
 xmlreq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
 var dados = 'questao=' + num + '&resposta=' + resposta;  //dados que estou enviando
 xmlreq.send(dados); //xmlreq = xmlhttp
```

Funcionou corretamente, obrigado. Se o seu não estiver enviando dê uma olhada nos campos do banco de dados, os que forem NOT NULL ou VARCHAR se estão recebendo valores de acordo.